# Retain <CfSelect> value as well as other form values on Self-Referencing form

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion, selection

I want to submit my form, then have the form self-reference itself and retain the values.

How can I set it up to retain which item I have selected? It can retain the value of the selected item upon the second form load?
All I know is that I may have to do a CFloop rather than run my query directly on the query attribute.

Heres my select code:

```
<cfselect Name="CandyLand" required="yes" size="6" 
Query="getCandyInfo" style="width: 200px" 
Value="UserID"  Display="Name" >
<Option selected="selected"></option>
</cfselect>
```

Edit:
Well it seems Dan's Solution works in the sense of how I asked the question. I forgot to mention that I have 3 other form objects where I want their form values retained upon form submit. For example I have a textbox, a 2 radio buttons, and a checkbox that I want to retain their values. The values are obtained through a **Bind** that changes the value of these objects when I click a different object in the `<Select>`.

For example:
`<cfinput name="Chocolate" type="checkbox" 
bind="cfc:Candyland.getFat({CandyLand@click})" bindAttribute="checked" value="#Form.Chocolate#">`

Upon submit despite retain the clicked item, all objects go blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cfselect has a selected attribute.  You just have to check to see if the form has been submitted.

```
if (StructKeyExists(form, "CandyLand"))
SelectedValue = Form.CandyLand;
else
SelectedValue = GetCandyInfo.UserID[1];


<cfselect name="CandyLand" etc
selected = SelectedValue>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're making your life harder for yourself by using `<cfselect>`. Just use a normal `<select>`, then set the appropriate option to be 'selected' via checking its value with the form submission.

```
<select name="CandyLand" [etc]>
    <cfloop query="getCandyInfo">
        <option value="#userId#"<cfif userId eq form.CandyLand> selected</cfif>>#name#</option>
[etc]
```

There is an active move in the CFML community to ditch this kind of cruft from the language, and encouraging people to use more robust solutions:

- [ColdFusion UI the Right WayColdFusion UI the Right Way](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way/blob/master/chapters/introduction.md)
- [I'm not going to tell you to stop using ColdFusion UI tags anymore...](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2014/1/23/Im-not-going-to-tell-you-to-stop-using-ColdFusion-UI-tags-anymore)
- [Oi! You bloody wankers! Stop using ColdFusion UI controls](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2014/01/oi-you-bloody-wankers-stop-using.html)